# WKWebView - Track progress of webview loading

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, wkwebview

I am using a `WKWebView` to load an `HTML` string ***using webview.loadHTMLString() method*** and I want to show a message when webview fails to load if there is no internet connection. I tried with delegate methods of `WKWebview` ***didFail*** but it is not going inside that method when there is no internet connection instead it is going inside ***didFinish*** method. So I am not able to differentiate between success and failure cases.

Edit:- I am loading an HTMLString which contains a websocket url

Answer (score 1):

You can add `progress` observer as below,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    self.webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.bounds, configuration: configuration)
    self.webView.navigationDelegate = self
    webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.estimatedProgress), options: .new, context: nil)
    self.view.addSubview(self.webView)

    self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.google.com/")!))
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if keyPath == "estimatedProgress" {
        print("Webview progress. \(Float(webView.estimatedProgress))")
    }
}
```

To get the internet connection error and finish callback, you can implement the `WKNavigationDelegate` `didFailProvisionalNavigation` and `didFinish` methods,

```
extension ViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        print(error)
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("Webview loaded successfully!")
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not going inside didFailProvisionalNavigation() or didFail() methods when network is not reachable it is going inside didFinish(). And I am not loading webview from url , I am loading an htmlString which has websocket url's.